# Browserify output code doesn't execute in browser

Tags: javascript, browserify

Probably this question was asked before, but I've read everything I found last 4 hours and I still don't understand how it works and I give up.
I have main.js with code:

```
var hello = require('./hello.js');
hello.helloWorld();
```

And hello.js with code:

```
exports.helloWorld = function () {
    alert('Hello browserify world!');
}
```

Then I do as said in docs:

```
browserify main.js -o packed.js
```

Resulting packed.js contains now:

```
(function e(t, n, r) {
    function s(o, u) {
        if (!n[o]) {
            if (!t[o]) {
                var a = typeof require == "function" && require;
                if (!u && a)return a(o, !0);
                if (i)return i(o, !0);
                var f = new Error("Cannot find module '" + o + "'");
                throw f.code = "MODULE_NOT_FOUND", f
            }
            var l = n[o] = {exports: {}};
            t[o][0].call(l.exports, function (e) {
                var n = t[o][1][e];
                return s(n ? n : e)
            }, l, l.exports, e, t, n, r)
        }
        return n[o].exports
    }

    var i = typeof require == "function" && require;
    for (var o = 0; o < r.length; o++)s(r[o]);
    return s
})({
    1: [function (require, module, exports) {
        (function e(t, n, r) {
            function s(o, u) {
                if (!n[o]) {
                    if (!t[o]) {
                        var a = typeof require == "function" && require;
                        if (!u && a)return a(o, !0);
                        if (i)return i(o, !0);
                        var f = new Error("Cannot find module '" + o + "'");
                        throw f.code = "MODULE_NOT_FOUND", f
                    }
                    var l = n[o] = {exports: {}};
                    t[o][0].call(l.exports, function (e) {
                        var n = t[o][1][e];
                        return s(n ? n : e)
                    }, l, l.exports, e, t, n, r)
                }
                return n[o].exports
            }

            var i = typeof require == "function" && require;
            for (var o = 0; o < r.length; o++)s(r[o]);
            return s
        })({
            1: [function (require, module, exports) {

            }, {}]
        }, {}, [1]);

    }, {}]
}, {}, [1]);
```

Which looks the same whatever original main.js contains (I tried some big react js code).
According to the docs, I just need to include it to my page in `<script>` tag.
Surely, it doesn't work. So what's wrong? Two functions are exactly the same.
I'd skip it, but I cannot as I need React Router which dependencies are supposed to be resolved this way...

UPDATED: added another try according to the NodeJS style.

_______________UPDATE_________________
It seems I spent too long sitting in front of my laptop. I confused paths to files, so tried to process empty file.

Comment: Something isn't right. If you look at the output it does not contain any of your input code in it so it is not actually executing anything useful.

Comment: Yes, that's it. Please see my latest update

Answer (score 0):

Browserify is designed to take Node.js style code and make it work in the browser. This means that you should use the Node.js/CommonJS module style.

You don't need to use `window.onload` as anything in your main js file will just execute.

If you want to use react, you will need to install the module with NPM and then require it in your JS file.

```
var react = require('react');

react.blah();
```

Try following a guide like http://www.sitepoint.com/getting-started-browserify/ and if you can get it working with that than you can use it as a starting point for your code.

Comment: Thanks for the link, I saw it before and tried it. I updated my post, could you please check it again.